# ckeditor 4.3.3 enable file browser/uploader

Tags: file, browser, ckeditor

I am making a cms and I am using ckeditor as the wysiwyg editor.now i would like to enable upload of images from the local file system,but i am stucked!
I google this problem and find many answers about this!but the answers seem not solve my problem.I do some work try to enable the file browser as follows,but it can't work:

```
1.I download the ckeditor "Standard Package".
2.I add ckeditor to my page as the official doc says and it work well.
3.I download the add-ons "File Browser" and "Popup" from the add-ons part of ckeditor.com.
4.I set the config in "ckeditor/config.js",
  config.extraPlugins = 'popup,filebrowser';
```

I do all of these,but it still can not display the "file browser" button,can anyone tell me where I am wrong and if I need to do some extra work and config?
also,I am using ckeditor with php!

Comment: it is only part of task, now you need to set EXTERNAL FILE BROWSER as stated on website "This plugin is to integrate the editor with external file browse/upload application"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to browse your directory on server and find your files what error showed up to you?

/////////////
Edited
/////////////

I think your problem is so close to this comment please check it

http://ckeditor.com/comment/59021#comment-59021

Comment: there is no error,I just can not find the file browser tab in the toolbar.

Comment: Did you check the link? and if it help you please let me know.

Comment: ,I click the link and it can work!but I don't want to use CKFinder in my project.still thank you very much!